# Count frequency of elements matching other elements of another column in R

Tags: r, database, data-manipulation

Say I have

```
Name<- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
Cate<- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "c", "b", "b", "c")
```

I want to reproduce the following:

```
Nam fra frb frc
A   2   2   1
B   3   0   1
C   0   2   1
```

Where `fra`, `frb` and `frc` are the frequency values of a, b and c values respectively in `Cate` for each category (A,B,C) of `Nam`.

I am looking for a faster code than the one I am using (subsetting Nam in each category and then calculate the frequencies)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930879/problems-with-aggregating-and-crosstabulating-data

Comment: Just use `tab<-table(Name,Cate)`and `colnames(t)=c('fra','frb','frc')`.

Comment: And do not forget to put quotes for `Name` and `Cate` values but I guess you just forgot it for the exemple.

Answer (score 3):

We can do a `dcast` from `data.table` which is very efficient and quick

```
library(data.table)
dcast(data.table(Name, Cate), Name ~paste0("fr", Cate))
#   Name fra frb frc
#1:    A   2   2   1
#2:    B   3   0   1
#3:    C   0   2   1
```

---

A simple `base R` option would be

```
table(Cate, Name)
```

#### data

```
Name <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
Cate <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "c", "b", "b", "c")
```

Comment: `Name` should have 5As, 4Bs and 3Cs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `xtabs()` function:

```
    xtabs(~Name + Cate)
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, here's a Hadleyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(Name, Cate) %>%
  count(Name, Cate) %>%
  spread(key = Cate, value = n, fill = 0)
```